# Count number of rows where the minimum of multiple columns is less than a specific number

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to do this in Google Sheets, but couldn't really figure out the syntax - not quite sure whether I should be starting with COUNTIF, ARRAYFORMULA, or something else.

e.g.

[image: Screenshot]

How would I have a formula that would count the number of rows, if the minimum for each row between columns A-C is less than 2? In this case, the result should be 3.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain little more. What do you mean by Between columns A-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en):

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(A1:C5,"select COUNT(A) where A<2 or B<2 or C<2 label COUNT(A) ''", 0),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks all - appreciate the responses!

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data setup, this should work:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(A:A,(A:A<2)+(B:B<2)+(C:C<2)))`

Comment: Thanks all - appreciate the responses!